# Keras neural network to predict change in angle of a particle is not predicting correctly

Tags: python, keras, neural-network

I have put together a keras regresssion model to predict the change in angle of a single particle when supplied with data about that particle. To aquire the data, I created a program that models brownian motion between n particles. As well as random angular noise, depending on how close together the particles are they will induce a change in each others angle.

It is not too important how my code works, but essentially it outputs an array containing the x,y coordinates of all particles relative to the single particle, the value of theta of all particles, and the distance between all particles and the single particle. All of these parameters are found at each time step. Each 'image' I use to train the network is all these parameters at some point in time. So overall, the input variable is x,y,angle,distance, and the output variable is the change in theta of the target particle

For my neural network I first normalised all my data to be between -1 and 1, and then reshaped it to be fed into the NN:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.layers import Dropout

## NORMALIZE IMAGES ##########################################################

# all images and labels imported, so obviously wont run without data. This is
# designed for running data with m iterations, n particles, 4 parameters
# (size of test data array is [m,n,4]). 

L = 5
# length of 'box' that houses particles
n = 10
# number of particles

train_images[:,:,0:2] = train_images[:,:,0:2]/L
# normalise [x,y] from -L:L to -1:1.
train_images[:,:,2:3] = train_images[:,:,2:3]/(2*np.pi)
# normalise theta value from -2pi:2pi to -1:1
train_images[:,:,3:4] = (train_images[:,:,3:4]/(L*np.sqrt(2))*2)-1
# normalise distance value from 0:sqrt(2)L to -1:1

test_images[:,:,0:2] = test_images[:,:,0:2]/L
test_images[:,:,2:3] = test_images[:,:,2:3]/(2*np.pi)
test_images[:,:,3:4] = (test_images[:,:,3:4]/(L*np.sqrt(2))*2)-1

## FLATTEN IMAGES ############################################################

train_images = train_images.reshape((-1, 4*(n-1))) 
# reshape so each input is a single dimension
# 4*(n-1) due to 4 parameters, adn n-1 particles (since one is redundant info)
test_images = test_images.reshape((-1, 4*(n-1)))

## BUILDING THE MODEL ########################################################

model = Sequential([
  Dense(64, activation='tanh', input_shape=(4*(n-1),)),
  Dense(16, activation='tanh'),
  Dropout(0.25),
  Dense(1, activation='tanh'),
])

## COMPILING THE MODEL #######################################################

model.compile(
  optimizer='adam',
  loss='mean_squared_error',
  #metrics=['mean_squared_error'],
)

## TRAINING THE MODEL ########################################################

history = model.fit(
  train_images, # training data
  train_labels, # training targets
  epochs=10,
  batch_size=32,
  #validation_data=(test_images, test_labels),
  shuffle=True,
  validation_split=0.2,
)
```

I have used a variety of activation types for the different layers (relu, sigmoid, tanh...), but none seem to give me the correct results. The true values of my data (the change in angle of the particle) are values ranging from about 0.02 to -0.02, but the values I am getting are much smaller, and tend to be predominantly one sign (pos/neg).

I am currently using the loss function 'mean absolute error', as I am looking to minimise the difference between the real and predicted value. I notice when doing this, that after only one epoch the loss is already incredibly tiny:

```
Epoch 1/10
12495/12495 [==============================] - 13s 1ms/step - loss: 0.0010 - val_loss: 3.3794e-05
Epoch 2/10
12495/12495 [==============================] - 13s 1ms/step - loss: 3.4491e-05 - val_loss: 3.3769e-05
Epoch 3/10
12495/12495 [==============================] - 13s 1ms/step - loss: 3.4391e-05 - val_loss: 3.3883e-05
Epoch 4/10
12495/12495 [==============================] - 13s 1ms/step - loss: 3.4251e-05 - val_loss: 3.4755e-05
Epoch 5/10
12495/12495 [==============================] - 13s 1ms/step - loss: 3.4183e-05 - val_loss: 3.4273e-05
Epoch 6/10
12495/12495 [==============================] - 13s 1ms/step - loss: 3.4175e-05 - val_loss: 3.3770e-05
Epoch 7/10
12495/12495 [==============================] - 13s 1ms/step - loss: 3.4160e-05 - val_loss: 3.3646e-05
Epoch 8/10
12495/12495 [==============================] - 13s 1ms/step - loss: 3.4131e-05 - val_loss: 3.3629e-05
Epoch 9/10
12495/12495 [==============================] - 14s 1ms/step - loss: 3.4145e-05 - val_loss: 3.3581e-05
Epoch 10/10
12495/12495 [==============================] - 13s 1ms/step - loss: 3.4148e-05 - val_loss: 3.4647e-05
```

Here is an example of the results I get from this:

```
Prediction:  4.8542774e-05
Actual:  0.006994473448353978
```

Is there anything obviously wrong I have done to get these results? Sorry if I have not provided enough information.

Answer (score 0):

It is a regression problem,last layer does not have activation. Decrease the number of unit frim 32 to 16 in 1 st layer as this will prevent overfiting

Comment: Hi @SarthakBansal, thanks for the reply! I have tried this and my results have not improved, the predisction remain orders of magnitude below the real answers. Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: Try adding a lambda later at the  last layer to multiply the result by 100. 
 model.add(Lambda(lambda x: x *100))